# IIS URL Rewrite some rules overriding other rules

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, microservices

We are in the process of breaking our main site into micro services.  Initially as we break out a piece of the site it will become it's own site on our original server until it can move to it's own container.

This site is currently an angular site, so you see we have the rule to rewrite everything to go to the index.html.  I'm trying to add on an additional rule so if it finds the url. `www.domainname.com/api/auth/.*` to `localhost:8001/{R:1}`

My understanding is it will take everything from the url after the /auth/ and change it to localhost:8001/{stuff after}

What's happening though is it is following the rule to point everything to the index file and seems to be ignoring my new rule.  I've tried it first and last, so I'm assuming there must be something wrong with my rule.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Api Rule">
                    <match url="domainname.com/api/auth/.*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost:8001/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />   
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domainname\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainname.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are evaluated in the same order in which they are specified. (from documentation : [URL rewrite module configuration reference - rules evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rules-evaluation))

the `url` attribute of the `match` element works with the PATH part of the URL. You should not specify domain.

```xml
<rule name="Api Rule">
    <match url="^api/auth/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost:8001/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

if you want to match with domain you can add a condition

```xml
<rule name="Api Rule">
    <match url="^api/auth/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost:8001/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```